# When to load an image to use the Javascript function drawImage()?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use the drawImage() function to load an image in a Javascript animation, but the image does not load with my current code.  I think I need to specifically ask for the image to be loaded at some point, but I'm not sure when or how.  The idea is to make a cloud that goes across the canvas. Thank you for your help.

```
function draw(x,y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    x += 2;
    if(x>1000){
        x=0;
    }

    var cloud = new image();
    cloud.src='small_cloud.png';
    ctx.drawImage(cloud,x,0);

    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',20);

}
```

Comment: When drawImage executes, has small_cloud.png actually been loaded? There's only a 1 micro-second or so gap between the two commands :) So there may not BE an image to draw by the time drawImage is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `new Image()`rather than `new image()`

Also move

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
var cloud = new image();
cloud.src='small_cloud.png';
```

to outside the `draw()`function, as you only want to set these things up once. Delay this setting up until the browser has had time to parse the document, for example using

```
window.onload = function(){ ... };
```

(Though in reality you'd have to make sure not to overwrite any existing window.onload listeners by using proper even handler registration.) Also delay the first invocation to `draw()`until the image has loaded, for example like so:

```
cloud.onload = function(){
    draw(cloud, 0, 0);
}
```

I'd also change

```
var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',20);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function(){ draw(x, y); }, 20);
```

since you seem not to be using the loopTimer variable, and since passing setTimeout an anonymous function rather than a string is considered better practice.

Finally, it would look like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
    var cloud = new image();
    cloud.src='small_cloud.png';    
    cloud.onload = function(){
        draw(ctx, cloud, 0, 0);
    };
};

function draw(ctx, cloud, x,y){
    x += 2;
    if(x>1000){
        x=0;
    }

    ctx.drawImage(cloud,x,0);

    setTimeout(function(){ draw(ctx, cloud, x, y); }, 20);
}
```

Note that, since ctx is no longer defined inside the draw() function, as it is local to the anonymous window.onload function, you also has to pass ctx to the draw() function.

Comment: Great answer, thanks so much for the help.  Its working now, except that there is a flicker that was not there when I tested it with fillRect(). Is that happening because of a delay in drawImage()?

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help! I just realized two other important things that should be moved to outside the draw() function, please see edited answer. I guess those improvements may well help the flicker. Otherwise I'm not sure what could cause it, as I'm not very experienced working with canvas.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why, but when I moved those two lines out of the draw() function it stopped working all together.

Comment: Ok. You have to make sure that `ctx`is global, so that it can be referenced from within the draw() function. Also, you want to delay the looking up of the canvas. I'll update my answer.